# No sooner did or No sooner had

Tags: conjunctions

This question came in my exam and answer was (c)

> No sooner ...... than the police handcuffed him.
>
> (A) he came
>
> (B) did he came
>
> (C) did he come  (Ans)
>
> (D) had he come

But i dont know why teacher rejected 4th option.

Comment: D reads better to me too, but C is okay.  A and B are wrong.  Mostly-UK native speaker here.

Answer (score 3):

Both C and D are correct.

Note that the constructions of this form using "did" or "had" are not identical. "Did" uses simple present tense, while "had" uses the past participle. For the verb "to come," these happen to be the same word:

No sooner did he come (present tense) than the police handcuffed him.

No sooner had he come (past participle) than the police handcuffed him.

In contrast, you would say "no sooner did he go" but "no sooner had he gone," for example.